# using X11 library in C programming

Tags: c, visual-studio, x11-forwarding, xming

I am using X11 library in my C code. I downloaded the Xming and PuTTY softwares and using the PuTTY interface I need to do the X11 forwarding. If anyone has done it before, could he/she help me about this? Another question is that, how should I call that library in my code?  Is it okay to use the following lines in my code?

```
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
```

Also, when I run this code I got the following errors:

cannot open source file "X11/Intrinsic.h"
cannot open source file "GL/glx.h"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to install X11 and OpenGL libraries on the computer you are compiling on, and set up paths to their include directories in your compiler. Get it working locally. Forwarding should work without changes to your program.

Comment: Do you mean Xming instead of X11?   I mean, I have googled and could not find any X11 library for windows, therefore I have to use PuTTY to forward X11. Am I wrong?

Comment: Xming is an (old an unsupported unless you make a donation) implementation of the X11 *server*. It may or may not include the X11 *libraries* you need for development. The easiest way to install X11 on Windows is to use cygwin, it has the server and the libraries. No, you don't have to forward anything or use PuTTY. I personally recommend developing on Linux.